# How do you launch an application.app stored in nfs share from bash script?

Tags: applications, bash, nfs

I need to run `*.app` from our NFS share where the different apps and versions are stored.

I can't get it to work as part of a bash script.

For exemple, for Sublime Text, here is the command I use to launch:

```
elif [ `uname` == "Darwin" ]; then
    exec open -a "/path/to/nfs/"Sublime\ Text.app" "$@"
fi
```

When I call my script, I get the following error:

```
FSPathMakeRef(/path/to/nfs/Sublime Text.app) failed with error -43.
```

I know the path is right. Permissions are also fine. 
I'm able to launch it with the full path `exec open -a "/path/to/nfs/"Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/MacOS/"Sublime\ Text"" "$@"` but then all the content of the .app folder isn't available.

Is there another way to launch .app from command line?

Comment: -43 == file not found. foo.app should be in `/path/to/nfs/foo/Contents/MacOS/foo.app` though idk if it will work from an nfs.

Comment: Why are you using `exec`? What's the purpose of `"$@"`? What happens if you just use: `open -a "/path/to/nfs/Sublime Text.app"` It works for me. BTW Don't escape _spaces_ with a _backslash_ and _quotes_, use one or the other, not both.

Comment: I can indeed remove the exec command. For the "$@", it allows me to pass argument when my command is part of a script: "my_script /path/to/file/"

Comment: @user3439894, your command indeed works when launched from a terminal but not when being part of a script.

Comment: First of all, my _command_ as written does indeed work from a `bash` script, to open Sublime Text! Secondly, you never mention in your OP that this was part of a _script_ and why I questioned what `"$@"` was for. BTW I know what `"$@"` is for as I've read the `bash` man page more then once, but in the context of your OP it made no sense because you didn't say your were executing it in _script_! Obviously in a _script_ that you want to pass arguments to my _command_, it would be `open -a "/Volumes/Data/Temp/Sublime Text.app" "$@"` and it works!

Comment: You're right. I should have specify it was part of a script. I'll test your solution today and let you know. I'll also edit my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary issue I see with your *command*:

```
exec open -a "/path/to/nfs/"Sublime\ Text.app" "$@"
```

Is you have used a *backslash* to escape a *space* while also *quoting* the *command*. Use one or the other, but not both, e.g.:

```
open -a "/path/to/nfs/Sublime Text.app"
```

Or:

```
open -a /path/to/nfs/Sublime\ Text.app
```

I also see no reason to use `exec` when the `open` *command* by itself works in this context, or from a *script*, e.g.:

```
open -a "/path/to/nfs/"Sublime Text.app" "$@"
```

That said though, when using the `open` *command* with the `-a` *option* you might consider using the `--args` *option*, which from its man page states, "All remaining arguments are passed to the opened application in the argv parameter to main(). These arguments are not opened or interpreted by the `open` tool.", thus making the *command* as, e.g.:

```
open -a "/path/to/nfs/"Sublime Text.app" --args "$@"
```